# Build libmxnet.dll for windows

Tags: visual-studio-2015, mxnet

I am following http://mxnet.io/get_started/windows_setup.html to generate libmxnet.dll using the prebuild package for windows.

I have downloaded the nightly prebuild release from windows here https://github.com/yajiedesign/mxnet/releases packe 20170624_mxnet_x64_vc14_gpu.

Step 4 in the procedure request that I should build the windows studio solution to generate the libmxnet.dll. This step does not mention the name or location of the solution file, so I have searched for *.sln and *.suo but it is nowhere.

Does anybody know if I have picked the wrong package for download or what else can be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a pip package for windows available [MXNet Windows pip package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mxnet-cu80-win).

Comment: and `libmxnet.dll` is found in `Lib\site-packages\mxnet`